# How to put value over bars when creating many barplots with a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, plot-annotations

How can I put the value over the bars when creating many plots with a loop.

The code I am using

```
years = [twenty,twentyone,twentytwo,twentythree]

for year in years:

   plt.ylim(0, 60)
   ax = sns.barplot(data=year, errorbar=None)
   ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
   for i in ax.containers:
       ax.bar_label(i,)
   
   
   plt.xlabel('Type of error')
   
   
   # Set plot title and save image
   if year is twenty:
       plt.title('2020')
       plt.savefig(f'barplot_2020.png',bbox_inches="tight")


   
   elif year is twentyone:
       plt.title('2021')
       plt.savefig(f'barplot_2021.png',bbox_inches="tight")
       
   
   elif year is twentytwo:
       plt.title('2022')
       plt.savefig(f'barplot_2022.png',bbox_inches="tight")
   
   elif year is twentythree:
       plt.title('2023')
       plt.savefig(f'barplot_2023.png',bbox_inches="tight")
       #ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0],fmt="%.1f")
```

I have tried also to put some code in the `if`s as shown in the last `elif` but the result is always the same as shown below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The only issue is, you must have `plt.show()` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're missing a [`plt.figure()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html) command in the beginning of your loop.

`plt.figure()` instructs `matplotlib` to create a new empty figure.
Currently you're constantly modifying the same figure, thus the bars overwrite each other.

We can fix this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

twenty = {'Type of error': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Count': [25, 35, 42]}
twentyone = {'Type of error': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Count': [30, 40, 38]}
twentytwo = {'Type of error': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Count': [28, 33, 45]}
twentythree = {'Type of error': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'Count': [32, 38, 40]}

years = [twenty, twentyone, twentytwo, twentythree]

for year, data in zip(range(2020, 2024), years):
    plt.figure()  
    
    plt.ylim(0, 60)
    ax = sns.barplot(data=data, x='Type of error', y='Count', errorbar=None)
    ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
    
    for p in ax.patches:
        ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt="%.1f")
    
    plt.xlabel('Type of error')
    plt.title(str(year))
    plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is not correct; `plt.figure()` is not required, and it switches from the matplotlib implicit interface to the explicit interface. The only issue is `plt.show()` is not present inside the loop of the OP. Also you used `ax.text` for annotations, but the current correct accepted implementation is with `ax.bar_label` , as done in the OP.

Comment: Thanks i really didn't know that you don't need `plt.figure`... So how does OP do it if they don't wanna `plt.show()`? Because OP is just saving the figures. Should they include `plt.show()` anyway? I've been doing text forever, i changed it to `ax.bar_label`, much better.

Comment: If the OP does not want to view the plots, then I would define the subplots and figure as in the duplicate, I recommend always using the explicit "axes" interface `fig, axes = plt.subplots(...)`

Comment: I would not recommend `subplots` to anyone, personally, especially not a newbie. `plt.figure()` does the trick for OP

Comment: That may be your personal preference, but it is not the position recommended by `matplotlib`. See [Why be explicit?](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#why-be-explicit)